# How to sum divs values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sum, each

I have some divs that have values. I want to sum in one `<h3>`
The probem in my code is that I get the last div value and cannot sum the other.

Html code:

```
<div class="cart-footer">
      <div class="order-tools">
        <h3 id="total">

        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="cash-out">

      </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
var sum = 0;
$('#item-total').each(function(){
 var val = $.trim($(this).text());
 if (val) {
 val = parseFloat(val.replace(/^\$/, ""));
 sum += !isNaN(val) ? val : 0;
 }
});
$("#total").html(sum + "$");
```

You can see `#item-total` in this code:

```
$(".cart-body").append(function(){
     return "<div id='cart-list'><div class='product-name'>"+personObject.name+"</div><div class='product-tools'><input type='number' data-id='1' value='1' min='1'></input><label id='price'>Price: "+personObject.price+"</label><label data-value='"+personObject.count * personObject.price+"' id='item-total'>"+personObject.count * personObject.price+"</label></div></div>";
   });
```

Comment: Since IDs must be unique `$('#item-total').each` doesn't make sense

Comment: How? I did not understand you

Comment: Do you have more than one element with the ID `item-total`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: Yes I have more than one @j08691

Comment: The idea is I want to sum `item-total`

Comment: You can't re-use IDs. They're unique. Try using classes instead.

Comment: I tried it .. it is the same value I'm getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with a logic error in your code. What you are doing incorrectly is looping through `$('#item-total')`. This is wrong because `#item-total` is selecting a **single unique** HTML element.

What you want to do is loop through all the elements using a different selector. For example by replacing in your HTML: `<h3 id="total">` into `<h3 class="total">`.

Now in your JQuery, selecting `$('.total')` would then select **all instances** of `.total` tagged HTML elements.

```js
var items = $('.item'),
    cashOut = $('#cash-out'),
    sum = 0;

$.each(items, function(value) {
  // items[value] will contain an HTML element, representing an 'item'.
  var itemValue = parseFloat(items[value].innerHTML);
  sum += !isNaN(itemValue) ? itemValue : 0;
});

cashOut.html('Total: $' + sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-footer">
  <div class="order-tools">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="cash-out">0</div>
```

Comment: But I want to sum `item-total`

Comment: How many `item-total` do you have? Do you want to sum `item-total` into something else or with each other?

Comment: it is a cart and maybe there is more every time

Comment: then do **not** use an `id='item-total'`, instead use `class='item-total'`. Please understand the difference between using **id** and **class**

Comment: I have did it and same value I got

Comment: @MousaSaleh I got busy for a while, I updated my answer with a JSFiddle. I changed the `<h3>` for `<div>` instead, it makes more sense in HTML and you should set the style of the `.item` using CSS as these do not represent **headings** :)